# how to set a timer or delay on some function

Tags: android, delay

I have a Bluetooth bcr hooked up to my tablet. I want it to clear the textbox if it doesn't start with a `R`. The problem is that there is Inter-Character delay(around 5ms) on it to prevent data loss during the transmission so it had already cleared out the `EditText` before is done typing. So the barcode that is called `KM70083` looks like `M70083` in the EditText, so it actually only deletes the first character instead of clearing the whole EditText

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    final String text = shelfnumberbox.getText().toString().trim();
    if (text.matches("K")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First charater has to be R", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        shelfnumberbox.setText("");
        shelfnumberbox.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `editText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                
            }
        }, 500);`

Comment: Also your code is using matches, which is a regex expression, perhaps you should consider just looking at the first character each time instead of the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `if` statement to be `if(!text.startsWith("R"))`. That way you will clear out the text regardless of how many characters are in the string.

Comment: then i get #21: Error inflating class <unknown>
at                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First charater has to be R", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        shelfnumberbox.setText("");

Comment: the issue was with the (! after removing that i worked fine but i still had to use the                     shelfnumberbox.postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {
                        shelfnumberbox.setText("");
                        shelfnumberbox.requestFocus();
                    } }, 1250);
as  Vucko helped with
to get it to work probaly

but i also thinks that this one is better  as i think it will also clears out the text if the shelf contians a R letter in the middle of the text

Answer (score 0):

Use TextWatcher afterTextChanged() method to do your work. You can use a timer and schedule your cleaning task there.